# Excel formula on two sigma std of the results

Tags: excel

Lets say I have an array of numbers:

> 100,95,90,0.5

I would like to do some regular function on them such as Count, AVG, STD, MIN, MAX
which are all very simple.

but after that, I want to filter the array for 2 sigmas so the array will be

> 100,95,90

And then do all these functions once again and show the differences.
any advice?

Comment: What have you yourself tried so far? COUNTIFS, AVERAGEIFS, etc... STD may be slightly more complicated.

Comment: I dont really know how to start, a simple If for making a whole new array is possible, but it is very messy, I dont really know how to work with countifs

Comment: Did you try the [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842)?